# Empty body in retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

i have a scenario that when you do a PUT on a end point and get an OK http code 200, then you dont expect a body. However if the server returns a http code representing an error, it send a error json as a body.

How do i handle both cases? it seems you can only handle one of the other

```
@PUT("/path/to/get")
Call<Response<<Void>> getMyData(/* your args here */);
```

if i get a errorResponse body, it will obviously wont get the data response

or

```
@PUT("/path/to/get")
Call<Response<ErrorResponse>> getMyData(/* your args here */);
```

If the response is good then it tries to convert a body that has nothing and results to a java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: why dont you just always send a `ErrorResponse` then only check it if the server returns the http code that represents the error? If Http code of 200 just send blank data

Comment: use the `ResponseBody` from okhttp3 package as this: `Call<ResponseBody>`

Comment: Because like i said, if the response is 200, no response body, else they send a errorResponse json

Comment: @matrix that wont work. cant get the headers

Comment: what does the return type has to do with headers or not? You can put headers in the interface or intercept the request chain.

Comment: alot.. 

when i call a request, if it is successful i get a cookie in the header that represents my session for a set time. If the request is unsuccessful i get a error response object as a json response body and no cookie header.

I need the headers at response level, not request level! i can already add headers in request using intercept chain as you descrbed but i need headers from the response

Answer (score 2):

Use `ResponseBody` for such case:

```
service.getMyData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(), MyClass.class);
        } else {
            //Do something in case of error
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```